# I hope I don't regret this vs I hope I won't regret this

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between these two?

From my understanding:

***I hope I will not regret this*** - this means he has hope that in the future he will not regret something he has done (or will do).

***I hope I do not regret this*** - because of using "hope" before "don't" it seems he is referring to future as well (if I understand that correctly). I can't see a difference in meaning from the first one.

So do they actually mean the same or there is a difference?

Comment: The difference between them is no more than the difference between *I hope I will not become ill*, and *I hope I don't become ill*. And that is no difference at all.

Comment: What we will and what we do are inextricably connected. I *don't* smoke, because I *won't* smoke. What we will and what we do impact the future. I don't lie today, so I won't lie tomorrow either. *I hope I won't regret this* intersects with *I hope I don't regret this*: in the future, when the shit hits the fan.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. English only has two *inflected* tenses, past and nonpast. Whether a verb in the nonpast form refers to the present or future must be inferred from context.

When it would be unclear, we explicitly indicate a future time with time phrases such as *tomorrow*, or with auxiliary verbs such as *be going to*.